# Angular2 Detect Changes ON Rest Api

Tags: angular, angular2-services

i using simple Authentication service all data stored mysql i want detect changes on mysql and get changes put model i try ngDoCheck life cycle but ngDoCheck send api call every 1 sec and crash apache

User.Service

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';
import { User } from '../_models/user';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    private token: string;

    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
    }

    getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
        // Authorization Tokeni Ayarlanıyor
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': this.authenticationService.token });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        // Kullanıcı Headeri Gönderiliyor
        return this.http.get('http://localhost/Hesap/Detay', options)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json().detay); 
    }
}
```

Navbar Construct For user service check user detail

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../../_services/authentication.service';
import { User } from '../../_models/user';
import { UserService } from '../../_services/user.service';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
    selector: 'as-navbar',
    templateUrl: './navbar.html',
 styleUrls: ['navbar.component.css'],
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
 private isLoggedIn = false;
 users: User[] = [];
 

 constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private router: Router, private userService: UserService){}
 
 ngOnInit() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
   this.userService.getUsers()
            .subscribe(users => {
                this.users = users;
            });
            this.isLoggedIn = true;
       }else{
         this.isLoggedIn = false;
        }
 }

 logOut(){
  this.users = [];
  this.authenticationService.logout();
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
 }
}
```

Comment: " ngDoCheck life cycle but ngDoCheck send api call every 1 sec and crash apache" you can try to reduce the refresh time with some setTimeout mechanism.  But I think it's rather an architecture/design problem. Why you want to check the user every second?

Comment: thnks @jmachnik because user have credit and i want change on detect and print navbar

Comment: but why checking it periodically instead of checking this information when login occurs?

Comment: ahhhh yes! thanks for idea i update user model after credit purchase